# Как использовать Яндекс карты в Blender для построение города в 3D?

Tags: 3d, яндекс-карты, blender, моделирование

можно ли использовать Яндекс карты как гугл карты в Blender для построение города в 3D? если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: нет в BlenderGIS яндекса. Кто знает как добавить яндекс?

Answer (score 1):

Есть плагины "[BlenderGIS](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS)" или "YandexMapImporter", они позволяют импортировать данные из Яндекс карт в Blender. Для этого нужно установить BlenderGIS в блендер, выбрать провайдера Yandex, ввести координаты и масштаб, нажать `Import`. Profit!

Comment: Имейте в виду, пользовательские соглашения Яндекса использование своих карт и данных вне общедоступных сайтов не допускают.